# Change Column Type to "ORDSYS"."ORDIMAGE"

Tags: sql, oracle

Trying to change the column type from `BLOB` to to `ORDSYS.ORDImage` with the following code:

```
alter table "POSTS" 
modify ("IMAGE" "ORDSYS"."ORDIMAGE");
```

But it produces the following error:

```
ORA-22859: invalid modification of columns
```

The table and column names are definitely right.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be creating a new table via `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` statement, then drop the source table and rename the new one.

According to [Oracle Technology Network](https://community.oracle.com/thread/880012?tstart=0) you can create an `ORDImage` from a `BLOB` with

`select ordsys.ordimage(ordsys.ordsource(IMAGE, null, null, null, null, 1),
null, null, null, null, null, null, null) from POSTS`

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found was to drop the column and create a new one.